# How can I have a clickable anchor tag in the label of a vuetify text-field?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a SPA using Vue and Vuetify. One of my Vuetify text fields needs to have a anchor tag in the label. The link appears but is not clickable.

Here is an [HTML Fiddle](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%3Clink%20href=%22https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22wi$*$dth=device-wi$*$dth,%20initial-scale=1,%20maximum-scale=1,%20user-scalable=no,%20minimal-ui%22%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20i$*$d=%22app%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cv-app%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cv-main%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cv-container%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cv-text-field%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label=%22Product%20Code%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20placeholder=%22Product%20Code%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctemplate%20#label%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%3EProduct%20Code%20:%20(Find%20the%20product%20code%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22https://www.google.com%22%3Ehere%3C/a%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/h3%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/template%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/v-text-field%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/v-container%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/v-main%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/v-app%3E%0A%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%0A%20%20%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Vue(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20el:%20%27#app%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20vuetify:%20new%20Vuetify(),%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%3C/script%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%0A%3C/html%3E&css=&js=)

Here is a basic demo of my problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>

          <v-text-field
                        label="Product Code"
                        placeholder="Product Code">
            <template #label>
              <h3>Product Code : (Find the product code
                <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a>)
              </h3>
            </template>
          </v-text-field>


        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Update**
I've notice in the vuetify CSS there is `pointer-events: none;` ... seems that that is preventing the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you link inherit of the style applied on the H3 parent. So you just have to add a style tag to redefine this like :

```
<style>
  .v-text-field .v-label a{pointer-events:all;}
</style>
```